# Why can't you replace integers with lists using `replace` method - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, types

So let's say i have a pandas data-frame as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,0]})
```

So my goal is to replace `0` value with `[]` (empty list) in this dataframe, but i did:

```
print(df.replace(0,[]))
```

But it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'int'
```

I tried everything that's possible i.e:

```
df[df==0]=[]
```

etc...

But nothing works.

Desired output (in case for confusion):

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3 []
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible by list comprehension, but because mixed content - numeric with list it is not recommended:

```
df['a'] = [[] if x == 0 else x for x in df.a]

print (df)

    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3  []
```

And replace all values in all columns:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [] if x == 0 else x)
print (df)
    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3  []
```

Comment: Note that `[[]] * len(df)` may not work if `len(df) > 1`. It will create a list containing the same instance of empty list rather than `len(df)` unique empty lists, which is probably not what you wanted. You'll need to use list comprehension to create new lists.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. First is pandas' quirkiness when dealing with lists. To replace values in a DataFrame with list you need to do something like this;

```
df.loc[df.a == 0, "a"] = [[] for _ in df[df.a == 0]]
```

This creates `n` empty list based on the number of items that matches the criteria (`df == 0`)

The second issue is that your column is of integer type, and you can't store a list in an integer column. So before you can assign the list, you would first need to convert the column type to object first.

```
df = df.astype(object)
df.loc[df.a == 0, "a"] = [[] for _ in df[df.a == 0]]
```